# Equivalent norms?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

are the norms:

$\|P\|_1$= $\int^1_0\|P(t) \| dt$ and $\|P\|_2=sup_{0\le t\le1} |P(t)|.t$

equivalent on the vector space $X=\mathcal{P}[0,1]$, i.e. all polynomails on $[0,1]$?

could you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There norms are not equivalent: define $Q_N(t):=(N+1)\cdot t^N$. Then $\lVert Q_N\rVert_1=1$ for each $N$ but $\lVert Q_N\rVert_2=N+1$.

However, we always have the inequality 
$$\lVert P\rVert_1\leqslant \lVert P\rVert_1$$
for any $P\in\mathcal P[0,1]$.

Comment: i didnt understand the part: $\|Q_N\|_2=n$. could you plase elaborate.

Comment: $N+1=n$, i think

Comment: Yes (this because the supremum norm is attained at $t=1$).